# WAR deployment works fine, testing anything with Hibernate gives NoSuchMethodError

Tags: java, eclipse, hibernate, maven, jboss-logging

I'm getting the following error whenever I try to run some of my test cases:

This only happens when I'm running my tests, if I deploy and run the .war, everything runs fine. I've checked my project and the jboss folder and only one version of jboss-logging.jar is present. If I try to include org.jboss.logging.Logging in my project, everything is fine until it runs, at which point it throws the error there instead of when creating the SessionFactory.

pom.xml:

```
<build>
    <sourceDirectory>src</sourceDirectory>
    <resources>
        <resource>
            <directory>src</directory>
            <excludes>
                <exclude>**/*.java</exclude>
            </excludes>
        </resource>
    </resources>
    <testResources>
        <testResource>
            <directory>WEB-INF</directory>
            <targetPath>/WEB-INF</targetPath>
            <includes>
                <include>*.xml</include>
            </includes>
        </testResource>
    </testResources>
    <pluginManagement>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-resources-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.6</version>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.eclipse.m2e</groupId>
                <artifactId>lifecycle-mapping</artifactId>
                <version>1.0.0</version>
                <configuration>
                    <lifecycleMappingMetadata>
                        <pluginExecutions>
                            <pluginExecution>
                                <pluginExecutionFilter>
                                    <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
                                    <artifactId>aspectj-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                                    <versionRange>[1.0,)</versionRange>
                                    <goals>
                                        <goal>test-compile</goal>
                                        <goal>compile</goal>
                                    </goals>
                                </pluginExecutionFilter>
                                <action>
                                    <execute />
                                </action>
                            </pluginExecution>
                        </pluginExecutions>
                    </lifecycleMappingMetadata>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.1</version>
                <configuration>
                    <source>1.7</source>
                    <target>1.7</target>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <artifactId>maven-war-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.3</version>
                <configuration>
                    <warSourceDirectory>WebContent</warSourceDirectory>
                    <failOnMissingWebXml>false</failOnMissingWebXml>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <artifactId>maven-dependency-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.8</version>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <id>analyze</id>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>analyze-only</goal>
                        </goals>
                        <configuration>
                            <failOnWarning>true</failOnWarning>
                            <outputXML>true</outputXML>
                        </configuration>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.20.1</version>
                <dependencies>
                    <dependency>
                        <groupId>org.apache.maven.surefire</groupId>
                        <artifactId>surefire-junit47</artifactId>
                        <version>2.20.1</version>
                    </dependency>
                </dependencies>
            </plugin>

        </plugins>
    </pluginManagement>
</build>
<dependencies>
<!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/junit/junit -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>junit</groupId>
        <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
        <version>4.12</version>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>

    <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.apache.logging.log4j/log4j-core -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.logging.log4j</groupId>
        <artifactId>log4j-core</artifactId>
        <version>2.10.0</version>
    </dependency>

    <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.apache.logging.log4j/log4j-api -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.logging.log4j</groupId>
        <artifactId>log4j-api</artifactId>
        <version>2.10.0</version>
    </dependency>

    <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.apache.logging.log4j/log4j-web -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.logging.log4j</groupId>
        <artifactId>log4j-web</artifactId>
        <version>2.10.0</version>
    </dependency>

    <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/javax.servlet/javax.servlet-api -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
        <artifactId>javax.servlet-api</artifactId>
        <version>3.0.1</version>
    </dependency>

    <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/javax.servlet.jsp/jsp-api -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>javax.servlet.jsp</groupId>
        <artifactId>jsp-api</artifactId>
        <version>2.2</version>
    </dependency>

    <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.sun.mail/javax.mail -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.sun.mail</groupId>
        <artifactId>javax.mail</artifactId>
        <version>1.6.0</version>
    </dependency>

    <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.apache.struts/struts2-core -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.struts</groupId>
        <artifactId>struts2-core</artifactId>
        <version>2.5.14.1</version>
    </dependency>

    <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.apache.struts/struts2-json-plugin -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.struts</groupId>
        <artifactId>struts2-json-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>2.5.14.1</version>
    </dependency>

    <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.apache.struts/struts2-junit-plugin -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.struts</groupId>
        <artifactId>struts2-junit-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>2.5.14.1</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
        <artifactId>slf4j-log4j12</artifactId>
        <version>1.5.6</version>
    </dependency>

    <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/jstl/jstl -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>jstl</groupId>
        <artifactId>jstl</artifactId>
        <version>1.2</version>
    </dependency>

    <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.apache.taglibs/taglibs-standard-impl -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.taglibs</groupId>
        <artifactId>taglibs-standard-impl</artifactId>
        <version>1.2.5</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>taglibs</groupId>
        <artifactId>standard</artifactId>
        <version>1.1.2</version>
    </dependency>

    <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.mindrot/jbcrypt -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.mindrot</groupId>
        <artifactId>jbcrypt</artifactId>
        <version>0.4</version>
    </dependency>

    <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.hibernate/hibernate-core -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
        <artifactId>hibernate-core</artifactId>
        <version>5.1.10.Final</version>
    </dependency>

    <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.hibernate/hibernate-c3p0 -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
        <artifactId>hibernate-c3p0</artifactId>
        <version>5.1.10.Final</version>
    </dependency>

    <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.postgresql/postgresql -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.postgresql</groupId>
        <artifactId>postgresql</artifactId>
        <version>9.4.1211.jre6</version>
    </dependency>

    <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.apache.pdfbox/pdfbox -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.pdfbox</groupId>
        <artifactId>pdfbox</artifactId>
        <version>2.0.8</version>
    </dependency>

    <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.apache.poi/poi -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.poi</groupId>
        <artifactId>poi</artifactId>
        <version>3.17</version>
    </dependency>

    <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.apache.poi/poi-ooxml -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.poi</groupId>
        <artifactId>poi-ooxml</artifactId>
        <version>3.17</version>
    </dependency>

    <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.subethamail/subethasmtp-wiser -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.subethamail</groupId>
        <artifactId>subethasmtp-wiser</artifactId>
        <version>1.2</version>
    </dependency>

    <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.apache.commons/commons-email -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.commons</groupId>
        <artifactId>commons-email</artifactId>
        <version>1.3.1</version>
    </dependency>
    <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.jboss.logging/jboss-logging -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.jboss.logging</groupId>
        <artifactId>jboss-logging</artifactId>
        <version>3.3.1.Final</version>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>
```

stacktrace:

```
java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: org.jboss.logging.Logger.getMessageLogger(Ljava/lang/Class;Ljava/lang/String;)Ljava/lang/Object;
    at myproject.ComMappingTest.setUp(ComMappingTest.java:26)
    at junit.framework.TestCase.runBare(TestCase.java:139)
    at junit.framework.TestResult$1.protect(TestResult.java:122)
    at junit.framework.TestResult.runProtected(TestResult.java:142)
    at junit.framework.TestResult.run(TestResult.java:125)
    at junit.framework.TestCase.run(TestCase.java:129)
    at junit.framework.TestSuite.runTest(TestSuite.java:252)
    at junit.framework.TestSuite.run(TestSuite.java:247)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.JUnit38ClassRunner.run(JUnit38ClassRunner.java:86)
    at org.junit.runners.Suite.runChild(Suite.java:128)
    at org.junit.runners.Suite.runChild(Suite.java:27)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$3.run(ParentRunner.java:290)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$1.schedule(ParentRunner.java:71)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runChildren(ParentRunner.java:288)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.access$000(ParentRunner.java:58)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$2.evaluate(ParentRunner.java:268)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.run(ParentRunner.java:363)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit4.runner.JUnit4TestReference.run(JUnit4TestReference.java:50)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.TestExecution.run(TestExecution.java:38)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.runTests(RemoteTestRunner.java:467)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.runTests(RemoteTestRunner.java:683)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.run(RemoteTestRunner.java:390)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.main(RemoteTestRunner.java:197)
```

ComMappingTest.java:

```
package myproject.tests.com;

import java.util.List;

import junit.framework.TestCase;

import org.hibernate.Session;
import org.hibernate.Transaction;
import org.junit.AfterClass;
import org.junit.BeforeClass;
import org.junit.Test;

import myproject.hbos.com.CountryHBO;
import myproject.hbos.com.PortHBO;
import myproject.hbos.com.UserHBO;
import myproject.util.SessionManager;

public class ComMappingTest extends TestCase {

private static Session session = null;
private static Transaction tx = null;

@BeforeClass
public void setUp() {
    System.out.println(org.jboss.logging.Logger.Level.ERROR);

    session = SessionManager.getSession();
    tx = session.beginTransaction();
}

@AfterClass
public void tearDown() {
    tx.rollback();
    session.close();
}

@Test
@SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
public void testUserMaping() {
    List<UserHBO> users = (List<UserHBO>) session.createQuery("FROM UserHBO").setMaxResults(1).list();
    assertNotNull(users);
}

@Test
public void testPortMapping() {
    PortHBO port = (PortHBO) session.get(PortHBO.class, 8211);
    assertNotNull(port);
}

@Test
@SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
public void testCountryMapping() {
    List<CountryHBO> client = (List<CountryHBO>) session.createQuery("FROM CountryHBO").setMaxResults(1).list();
    assertNotNull(client);
}
}
```

Comment: What is your target container?

Comment: I'm using jboss-4.2.3.GA

Comment: Have you done an `mvn dependency:tree` to see if something else is pulling in a different version of `jboss-logging`?

Comment: Yep. The only version getting pulled is the one by hibernate-core.

Answer (score 0):

Your unit tests assume that the JBOSS logging JAR are in the CLASSPATH, but they are not.  The WAR deployment works because the JAR is present on the app server.

You can add the JAR dependency in your pom.xml and mark it as `<scope>test</scope>`

Comment: Added it and it still fails. I've updated my question to include that.
Also, looking at the dependency hierarchy, hibernate-core would have it anyways, no?

Comment: Probably a version conflict. The version your test wants does not include that method.

Comment: According to mvnrepository.com, Hibernate 5.1.10.Final should be using jboss-logging v3.3.0.Final, 3.3.1.Final as the updated version. Neither of those seems to do the trick. Any suggestions how I can find the version conflict/which version my test wants? I'm adding the test code to the question.

Comment: Find the version that Jboss uses and match it.

Comment: Ran a search in my jboss folder, there are no instances of jboss-logging besides what my project adds.

Comment: It's coming from somewhere.  You have to find where it's coming from in JBOSS.  The dependency is being satisfied when you run.   Since it's logging, could it be that your test needs to exclude something?  Logging is so confusing in Java: log4j, slif4j, commons logging, etc.